# Android Marshmallow porting to RPi 3

Tags: pi-3, android

I am trying out on Android Porting. Since I don't have any prior experience with porting, I decided to try porting Marshmallow(6.0.0_r5) to Raspberry Pi 3. As far as I know, and if I am wrong pls correct me, there are 3 basic things that are mainly required for running a bare minimum Android on RPi3

1. AOSP
2. Device Files
3. Device and Android compatible Linux kernel
4. Bootloader

I have been searching around, but all I have seen are abandoned projects. If possible pls can somebody guide me in the right direction as to where I can find the device files,kernel and the bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

A third party has already done a lot of work related to Android on the Raspberry Pi 3 [here](https://github.com/peyo-hd/device_brcm_rpi3).

Since the official forums dicourage discussion about Android , most communication happens through Google Groups : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-rpi